# Open hyperlink on a activeX control at cell click

Tags: excel, vba

i was trying to open a web page on excel using the activeX web control.
When using the navigate button control it work fines but when i change sheet and click on a cell it gives a "error 424 object is mandatory" (not sure if the translation is correct)
Any idea what to do here ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Not Cells(1, Target.Row).Value Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets("Browser").WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://127.0.0.1?loc=" & Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't your webbrowser control, it's your `if` statement (I suspect the code is stopping on that line). Specifically the use of `Is Nothing` is wrong here. Instead test the value of the cell for either the string `""` or `vbNull`.

```
If Not Cells(1, Target.Row).Value = vbNull Then
```

Comment: Thanks mate... indeed it was that.. Care to explain please the Not is nothing don't work there ? I means not is nothing isn't suppose to check be true is it has something ?

Comment: It's my experience that `IS NOTHING` is used on an object where `= vbNull` is more akin to `IS NULL` in SQL where you are checking if there is value in the non-object variable. Mileage may vary though since VBA is fickle. When in doubt, go with `NOT var = vbNull` or `var <> vbNull` and you are usually safe.